# Using a function with a string parameter for input validation

Tags: c++

I am in an intro to programming class for C++. It's not that hard for me, but this assignment is just confusing me.

The assignment is using two void functions, one will compute the area and perimeter of given length and width for a rectangle. The other is to compute the volume and surface area of the given length, width and height for a rectangular prism.

I have completed all of this so far and it works well, but there is a third int function that we are to use for input validation.

He wants us to make the function named "int promptForPostitiveNumbers(string ____)" Where we fill the blank with whatever name we want for the variable.

How exactly do I go about this if when calling the function its expecting a string and not a number for the lengths widths and heights?

Also this is my first time going to a forum for help with an assignment, so I am not sure what all I should include.

Edit: My professor requires every assignment to be done with the "using namespace std;" and I am only on my 13th week of classes so I'm still pretty basic when it comes to knowledge of C++

Comment: [The easy way is to use `std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to turn the `string` into a number (or die trying-remember to handle the exception) and then process the number normally. You can also short-circuit all of the conversion if the `string` starts with a `'-'` character.

Comment: Side note:  Stack Overflow isn't a forum. It's a Q&A. You ask a question, people offer answers. Don't use answers to communicate information with people unless it really is an answer. Amend the question with new information. You pick the most helpful of the answers that resolve your question as the "Official" answer. Don't accept right away. Test the answers first, and who knows? Someone might as a genius answer after a few less brilliant answers are posted.

Comment: Meant to mention this in the post I will edit it shortly. My professor requires every assignment to be done using namespace std. so I am not sure what std::stoi is.

Comment: `std::stoi` breaks down into the `stoi` function in the `std` namespace. That means you should be good. The only caveat is `stoi` isn't in older (pre 2011) versions of the C++ standard. If you're learning old C++, you'll have to use [`std::strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) or (sneaky sneaky) [`std::stroul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul). The u in `strtoul` stands for unsigned. It will reject a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Using namespace std is just for convenience and sometimes for shorter code as the compiler looks for functions by default in the std namespace. Example I can use

```
 using namespace std
 court<<"hello";
```

If I hadn't mentioned my namespace

```
std::cout<<"hello";
```

All of this assumes that I have the iostream header 
as for std::stoi is google it , the first link should be to the documentation , which should be self explanatory , if you still have doubts then come ask again